# Google Hangouts button width

Tags: button, size, google-hangouts

I need to ad hangouts button width. Don't really know where to put it? it should be like this  'widget_size': 175

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sunsää Seniortek </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
    </script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" width="1397" height="818" border="0" cellpadding="0"    cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
<iframe    src="http://example.com" width="1395" height="733" alt=""></iframe></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<img src="images/seniortek_02.png" width="1397" height="35" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">
<img src="images/seniortek_03.png" width="170" height="50" alt=""></td>
<td width="1046" height="31">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js">       </script>
<g:hangout render="createhangout"
invites="[{ id : 'mail@wxample.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
 </g:hangout></td>
<td rowspan="2">
<img src="images/seniortek_05.png" width="181" height="50" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/seniortek_06.png" width="1046" height="19" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea try read docs but can't figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the widget_size as mentioned below

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-rr"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 175
  });
</script>
```